# Infinite loading in double loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

So, I was coding a way to drop multiple lines of a DataFrame through a double loop that would check and compare every single row with all of the other rows:

```
catalogo0 = []
df6 = reviews.drop(reviews.columns[[4, 5, 6]], axis=1)
for i in range(len(df6)):
    estilo_culinario = ast.literal_eval(df6['Estilo Culinário'][i])
    for x in estilo_culinario:
        linha = ['{}'.format(df6['Nome'][i]), '{}'.format(df6['Cidade'][i]), '{}'.format(x), '{}'.format(df6['Ranking'][i])]
        catalogo0.append(linha)
df6b = pd.DataFrame(catalogo0, columns = ['Nome', 'Cidade', 'Estilo', 'Ranking'])
df6b.dropna(inplace=True)
for j in range(len(df6b)):
    for k in range(len(df6b)):
        if df6b['Cidade'][j] == df6b['Cidade'][k] and df6b['Estilo'][j] == df6b['Estilo'][k] and float(df6b['Ranking'][j]) >= float(df6b['Ranking'][k]):
            df6b.drop(j, inplace=True)
df6c = df6b.drop(df6b.columns[[2]], axis=1)
df6c
```

but by doing that, I got an infinite loading, that doesn't seem to end, which I suppose is a cause of the double loop. So, how could I fix this? Is there a way to compare every row of a df in a more efficient way? Because we are talking about a df with around 30.000 rows, so it's a hell of processing going on

Comment: Quick note: if you are doing a `for loop` on a dataframe, then you are probably doing something wrong. That should usually be your last option as it is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In fact your code is very complex, 2 nested loops + drop, so its O(n<sup>3</sup>).
Instead you can try this simple method:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
def drop_duplicate(df: pd.DataFrame):
    json_data = json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records"))
    unique_records = set([json.dumps(record) for record in json_data])
    return pd.DataFrame(data=[json.loads(str_record) for str_record in unique_records])[df.columns]

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 1,
    },
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 1,
    },
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
    },
])

print(drop_duplicate(df).head(10))
```

## Explanation

One of the best ways to deduplicate data in python is using set, the set loops over the data, hash them and keep only one instance of duplicated rows.
But series are unhashable, for this, I proposed to transform the dataframe in json str, load the json as a list of python dictionaries, then dump each dictionary (transform to string) to let the set hash it and add it.
Once the set is created, we can re-transform the unique string to dictionaries, and provide them in a list to `pd.DataFrame` to create a new dataframe. In this method the columns order may change, for this at the end, you can select `new_df[df.columns]` to get the same order as the input dataframe.

This solution may seem complex, but not, its complexity is O(n). You just need some extra memory to load the data and create the different data structures.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer btw. But I'm not familiar with the json library, so could you please clarify me about what your code is doing? Because I may have misinterpreted, but it looked like it dropped duplicate rows. However, my code is supposed to compare every two rows and drop one of them, but they are not identical. So I need a way to compare all rows in an efficient way. Anyway, if your code does indeed apply to my program, would you mind giving me an overview of the json commands you are using? I appreciate the help anyway

Comment: I explained the solution. In fact, comparing each row with other rows is a bad idea, because you loop over the data MxM times (M is the dataframe size), and the drop method is not simple, where pandas creates a new dataframe each time you drop a row, so you will loop over the data MxMxN (where N is the number of dropped rows). You can [read more](https://guides.codepath.com/compsci/Big-O-Complexity-Analysis) about complexity